# Listing multiple Redmine issues by Id

Tags: redmine

I am working on some custom Redmine reports. In the generated report, there are numbers that represent things like "number of issues moved to Development during Q3 2013". The report generator knows the issue id of every issue that matches that criteria.

Is there a way to construct a Redmine URL that shows a list of all issues given a list of issue ids? For example, something like (this doesn't actually work):

```
http://redmine/projects/example/issues?ids=1234,1239,1245
```

This is similar to existing feature requests such as http://www.redmine.org/issues/10828 but I'm looking for the user-facing HTML version, not an API function. The idea is to allow the user viewing the report to click on the number and to see the corresponding list of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I ended up with was to include the list of issues in a `<div>` for each number in the report that the user could click on. Then, when the user clicks on a number, the corresponding `<div>` is displayed using a jQuery UI dialog.

This is not the same as using the Redmine issue list screen to show the issues. However, for this purpose it works well enough.

Answer (score -1):

No, this is not implemented. But for me it should never be necessary in the Gui.

My Solution would be : Build the adequate query.

Eventually this will need the addition of a field in Redmine and backporting the information from your tool to Redmine. Generally the need for this feature shows your bug tracker lacks some information that he should track.

Comment: Redmine *does* track the state transition information in its database ("moved to Development" etc) but that information is not directly available using the Redmine query interface. So it is not possible to simply "Build the adequate query". That is why I needed to write a custom report.

Comment: According to you, your tool knows the id list, so your tool can update a custom field value in each issue and then give a link to a predefined query. Please reconsider down-voting, my answer "no" is the correct answer to your question, and I am suggesting a way to workaround this.

Comment: No, reports don't update custom field values. The same issue may appear in more than one report, so that can't work anyway. (And I didn't downvote.)